# node.js ошибка EADDRINUSE при перезапуске nodemon

Tags: node.js, nodemon

Пишу приложение и для этого используют nodemon в среде разработки.
У меня с какого то момента перестал перезагружаться, точнее перезагружается с ошибкой сервер при изменении файлов.
Ошибка:

```
events.js:167
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
  at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1330:14)
  at listenInCluster (net.js:1378:12)
  at Server.listen (net.js:1466:7)
  at Function.listen (.../server/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
  at Object.<anonymous> (.../server/src/index.js:53:5)
  at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
  at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
  at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
  at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:719:10)
  at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:228:19)
  at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:575:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
  at emitErrorNT (net.js:1357:8)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:174:19)
  at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:11)
  at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:228:19)
  at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:575:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Обычно эта ошибка возникает когда занят порт, порт у меня занят node

```
lsof -i tcp:3000
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    24290 ***   13u  IPv6 4328161      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
```

index.js весь не показываю

```
const app = express()
app.use(router)

app.listen(config.port, () => {
  global.console.log(`App is listening on port ${config.port}`)
  global.console.log('NODE_ENV: ', process.env.NODE_ENV)
})

process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  app.close()
})
```

Есть смежноe приложение которое я делаю параллельно, в принципе код почти совпадает, там этой проблемы нет. Пытался менять порт, работает одинаково.

Дополнение:
Сервер запускал через скрипт

```
"dev": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon -r dotenv/config ./src/index.js --trace-warnings",
```

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент у меня проблема решилась удалением флага -r из скрипта запуска сервера.

```
"dev": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon dotenv/config ./src/index.js --trace-warnings",
```

Так при сохранении файлов сервер перезагружается без ошибок.